# How would one solve a system by elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I solve a system by elimination?

I need to get the $x$ and $y$ variable out of the equation.

Use these parameters:

$$4x+10y=-4\\2x+10y=-12$$

Comment: a $y$ is missing in your first equation

Comment: Is your first equation written correctly?  If it is simplify it.

Comment: By..eliminating perhaps?

Comment: Do you understand why elimination is valid? Or do you at least know what elimination actually is going into the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subtract the two equations from each other as follows:

$$(4x + 10y = -4)\\-(2x + 10y = -12)$$ Yields $$4x + 10y - 2x - 10y = -4 + 12\\ 2x = 8\\ x = 4$$

Substituting back into the original equation we have: $$4x + 10y = -4\\ 4(4) + 10y = -4\\ 10y = -4 - 16\\ 10y = -20\\ y = -2$$

Comment: Will it always be subtraction, or is it just in a specific case?

Comment: In this specific case, subtraction was the easiest method to solve the equation. However, this does not always simplify the equation and there are a few other methods. The method I usually use which will always work is isolating for a single variable and then substituting the expression for that variable into the other equation.

Comment: I included your example as solved by substitution in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

after dividing by $2$ we get
$$2x+5y=-2$$
and
$$x+5y=-6$$
multiplying the first equation by $-1$ and adding to the second we get
$$-x=-4$$ can you finish?

Comment: You explained to OP how to solve this particular system of equations, but you didn't teach him how to do it for arbitrary parameters $a,b,c,d$.

Answer (score 0):

Using your example and by the method of substitution, this could be done as follows: 
$$4x + 10y = -4\\ 10y = -4 - 4x$$ 
Now substituting this expression in for 10y in the second equation yields:
$$2x + (-4 - 4x) = -12\\ 2x - 4x - 4 = -12\\ -2x = -8\\ x = 4$$ 
From here you can proceed by substituting the x value into the original equation as done before to get a value for y.